# Can I create a work item after a successful build in VSTS using built-in build definition tasks?

Tags: azure-devops

For one of my projects I would like to spawn a new task or story when a build completes successfully; is that possible using the built-in steps or build definition configuration? I haven't been able to figure out how, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll have to do some legwork.

You can write your own script to do so using the [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create) and call it using one of the shell tasks (PowerShell for Windows, shell script for Linux, etc).

Ex:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/Task?api-version=4.1
```

with the body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

will create a task with the title "Sample task".

Comment: Is the authentication for this already handled by the build host, or do I need to deal with that in PS?

Comment: There's a checkbox (I believe at the Phase level, but I could be misremembering) for "Allow scripts access to OAuth token". If that's checked, you can access a valid authentication token with the environment variable `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`.